# json retrival failed with jquery .each

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

```
{"paging":
    {"pageNum":2,
     "action":"Next",
     "type":"",
     "availableCacheName":"getAllFunds",
     "selectedCacheName":"",
     "showFrom":101,
     "showTo":200,
     "totalRec":289,
     "pageSize":100},

 "Data": [{"sourceCodeId":0,
           "radio_fund":"individual",
           "availableFunds":[],
           "fundId":288,
           "searchName":[],
           "fundName":"Asian Equity Fund A Class Income",
           "srcFundGrpId":"PGI",
           "firstElement":0,
           "lastElement":0,
           "totalElements":0,
           "pageList":[],
           "standardExtract":true}]
}
```

I have json file with above format with two fileds,one paging and one is Data array.

I able to retrieve values of paging,but i am not able to retrieve the values of data array with .each function of jquery.

Any suggestions or inputs really appreciated.

```
$.ajax({ url: "list.pubfw", 
         data :{action:action},
         dataType: "json",
         type:"POST",
         success: function(result){
                      var options = '';
                      $.each(result, function(){ 
                          options += '<option value="' + 
                              result.jsonData.fundId + '">' + 
                              result.jsonData.fundId + "-" + 
                              result.jsonData.fundName + "-" + 
                              result.jsonData.srcFundGrpId + '</option>'; 
                      }); 

                      $("#selectCol").empty(); 
                      $("#selectCol").html(options); 
                  }, 
         error: function(xmlHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
                    alert("ERROR"+errorThrown);
                    alert("STAT"+textStatus);                  
                    alert("xmlHttpRequest"+xmlHttpRequest); 
                } 
     });
```

Comment: Can you post the code? I tried with the json object and it works for me.

Comment: This is my code:   $.ajax({ url: "list.pubfw", data :{action:action},dataType: "json",type:"POST",success: function(result){var options ='';$.each(result, function(){options += '<option value="' + result.jsonData.fundId + '">' + result.jsonData.fundId + "-"+ result.jsonData.fundName + "-" +result.jsonData.srcFundGrpId+'</option>'; }); $("#selectCol").empty(); $("#selectCol").html(options); }, error: function(xmlHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){ alert("ERROR"+errorThrown); alert("STAT"+textStatus); alert("xmlHttpRequest"+xmlHttpRequest); } });

Comment: You should have edited your question to put the code neatly.

Comment: What's `data : {action,action}`? Especially, what is `action`?

Comment: What happens when you `alert(result)`? Do you get the expected JSON?

Comment: Hi sander,Sorry here action is "Next".I am getting result as object.

Comment: Shouldn't `result.jsonData` be `result.Data`?

Comment: Yes Rocket,I tried wth Data only.

Comment: I identified,one issue.With above fromat of json file ,Jquery able to retrieve very first eleemnt i.e in my case it paging.it is ignoring Data element.

Comment: How are you reading the data on the other side? You're aware that you're sending `"Next": Next`?

Answer (score 0):

There could be an error in the JSON validation, check [Json Lint](http://www.jsonlint.com/), since JSON is tricky.

Comment: I verfied already with jsonlit.there is no problem in JSON file,only problem with retrival .I dont kno whow to retrieve.I posted my code can you please check it and reply if any issues.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, here are two notes:
1.First of all you should use `result.Data` and not `result.jsonData`

2.the `Data` field holds an Array of objects you you'll have to loop over it or use indexes

3.If the `Data` field will not hold more than one Item then no need for the `$.each` method so you can easily use:
`result.Data[0].fundId` ..etc
But since it's an array of object then I would assume that it may contain more items so each is needed but not the way you are using it, instead use [this](http://jsfiddle.net/ifaour/NAZLJ/)

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you need to change the data part from:

```
data: {action: action}
```

To:

```
data: {"action": action}
```

This way, on the server side you can check the "action" property of the request coming in, instead of having the property name be as variable as its value.

On a side note, I would change your success function to:

```
success: function(result){
                  var selectCol = $('#selectCol');
                  selectCol.empty();

                  $.each(result, function(){
                      var option = $('<option/>');
                      option.val(result.jsonData.fundId);
                      option.text(
                          result.jsonData.fundId + "-" + 
                          result.jsonData.fundName + "-" + 
                          result.jsonData.srcFundGrpId);

                      selectCol.append(option);
                  }); 
              }
```

This keeps from building a (possibly) very big string, and it's also safer to use `text()` than `html()`, because `html()` will just insert anything that came in as html, leaving you vulnerable to XSS attacks. `text()` will html encode whatever comes in.